# Go websocket error: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF

Tags: go, websocket

I'm trying to write a simple go websocket server with gorilla/websocket

```
http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if os.Getenv("env") == "development" {
        upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
    }

    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Websocket error: %s", err)
        return
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    // Register client
    clients[conn] = true

    for {
        message := message.Message{}
        _, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Websocket error: %s", err)
            return
        }

        res, _ = json.Marshal(context.Game)

        // Send to every client that is currently connected
        for client := range clients {
            err := client.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, res)
            if err != nil {
                // Remove connection
                client.Close()
                delete(clients, client)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

the `_, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()` line is throwing an error and closing the websocket, but I'm not sure why.

The error is `close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF`. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Sounds like something client-side. Though I guess it's possible it's related to the race conditions on `clients`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón what's the best way to ignore that specific error? or I guess better track down the race condition?

Answer (score 11):

The error indicates that the peer closed the connection without sending a close message. The RFC calls this "abnormal closure", but the error is normal to receive.

Use [IsUnexpectedCloseError](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#IsUnexpectedCloseError) to filter out expected close errors.  The [Gorilla Chat Example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) shows how use the function ([view code here](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/b65e62901fc1c0d968042419e74789f6af455eb9/examples/chat/client.go#L65-L71)).

The application in the question has a data race on `clients` as pointed out by Adrian.  The Gorilla Chat Example shows how to maintain a map of clients without a data race ([hub](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat#hub)).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the disconnection between the server and the client itself, you may also need to pay attention to whether ws is disconnected due to the existence of intermediate proxy forwarding.

For example, after using the `nginx` reverse proxy, an error is reported after a certain period of time after connecting to sokcet, which is caused by an inappropriate timeout setting.

e.g.

```json
location /wss {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9091/ws;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_connect_timeout 4s;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        proxy_send_timeout 12s;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

Setting the `proxy_read_timeout time` to be greater than the heartbeat time of the server can solve this disconnection problem